# Ruby on Rails -- Saving and updating an attribute in a join table with has many => through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To simplify things, I have 3 tables :

Person

has_many :abilities, through => :stats

Ability

has_many :people, through => :stats

Stats

belongs_to :people

belongs_to :abilities

Stats has an extra attribute called 'rating'.

What I'd like to do is make an edit person form that always lists all the abilities currently in the database, and lets me assign each one a rating.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.  I managed to get it to work when creating a new user with something like this:

(from the people controller)

```
def new
 @character = Character.new
    @abilities = Ability.all
    @abilities.each do |ability|
        @person.stats.build(:ability_id => ability.id )
    end
end

From the people form:

<% for @ability in @abilities do %>
    <%= fields_for "person[stats_attributes]" do |t| %>
 <div class="field">
    <%= t.label @ability.name %>
    <%= t.hidden_field :ability_id, :value => @ability.id, :index => nil %>
    <%= t.text_field :rating, :index => nil %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This successfully gives me a list of abilities with ratings boxes next to them, and lets me save them if i'm making a new user.

The problem is that if I then load up the edit form (using the same form partial), it doesn't bring back the ratings, and if I save, even with the exact same ratings, it creates duplicate entries in the stats table, instead of updating it.

I realize I'm a terrible programmer and I'm probably doing this the wrong way, but how do I get the edit form to recall the current ratings assigned to each ability for that user, and secondly how do i get it to update the rating instead of duplicating it if the combination of person and ability already exists?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be

```
Character
has_many :stats
has_many :abilities, through => :stats

Ability
has_many :stats
has_many :characters, through => :stats

Stat
belongs_to :character
belongs_to :ability
```

?

Also, is it Person or Character?  You refer variously to both. (I'm going to go with Character in my answer)

I think you've fallen foul of the "I'll try to make a simplified version of my schema in order to attempt to illustrate a problem but instead make things more complex and muddle the issue by screwing it up so it doesn't make sense" syndrome.  Anyway, there's a couple of issues i can see:

1) first thing is that you're adding all the possible abilities to a character as soon as they're created.  This is silly - they should start out with no abilities by default and then you create join table records (stats) for the ones they *do* have (by ticking checkboxes in the form).

2) A simple way to manipulate join records like this is to leverage the "ability_ids=" method that the has_many :abilities macro gives you - referred to as "collection_ids=" in the api http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M001885&name=has_many

In other words, if you say

@character.ability_ids = [1,12,30]

then that will make joins between that character and abilities 1, 12 and 30 and delete any other joins between that character and abilities *not* in the above list.  Combine this with the fact that form field names ending in [] put their values into an array, and you can do the following:

```
#controller
def new
 @character = Character.new
 @abilities = Ability.all
end

#form
<% @abilities.each do |ability| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= t.label @ability.name %>
    <%= check_box_tag "character[ability_ids][]" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

#subsequent controller (create action)
@character = Character.new(params[:character]) #totally standard code
```

Notice that there's no mention of stats here at all.  We specify the associations we want between characters and abilities and let rails handle the joins.

Answer (score 0):

Railscasts episodes [196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) show how to edit several models in one form.  Example shown there looks similar to what you're trying to do so it might help you out (same episodes on ascicasts: [196](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), [197](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)).